How do I get a 404 error on blog detail pages in Angular?
When the URL is entered incorrectly, I get a 404 error on all pages, but I don't get this error even though I go to NotFoundComponent on the blog detail pages. My routers are as follows:
{
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent,
},
{
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent,
},
{
    path: 'blog/:slug',
    component: BlogDetailComponent,
},

I made some changes in Server.ts, but it didn't work and it got completely messy.

Not sure to understand what you want? you want to route in NotFound page when you are an error right ?

...but I don't get this error even though I go to NotFoundComponent on the blog detail pages. Can you elaborate on this? I don't understand what you want to do.

My router is in blog and blog/:slug format. I go to blog detail pages in blog/:slug format. For example, when I type contactasdfasdf on the contact page, it gives a 404 error, but if I type something wrong like blog/invalid-url on the blog/artificial-intelligence page, I continue to get a 200 status code on the network.

I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you give examples? For example, when I type contactasdfasdf on the contact page, it gives a 404 error..., what does this mean? Where do you type 'contactasdfasdf'? Do you want to limit slug values? If so, @Marc Guillem answer can help you. Make route guard and let request pass only if slug has allowed value. And if it doesn't have, then redirect to error page.

@MilosStojanovic I wrote all the paths into module.ts. I also have blog detail pages and I am getting the urls of these blog detail pages from somewhere else. I created a path like blog/:slug for that. But there is a problem, for example, when I write something randomly after the url on the contact page, it gives a 404 error, but when I write something randomly after the url on the blog detail page, it does not give a 404 error. All pages go to the NotFound page with the wrong url, but when I check the blog details from the network, it does not give a 404 error, it gives a status code of 200.

As i see your routes, the most practical and simple thing is to add a guard in the route where you have the parameter.
This guard will have to determine if the destination route with the parameter exists, if so, return true, if not, return false and make a redirection with the Router object to the NotFoundComponent component.
Route:
{
  path: 'blog/:slug',
  component: BlogDetailComponent,
  canActivate: [YourGuard]
}

YourGuard:
export const yourGuard: CanActivateFn = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
  // Do your logic here to determine if the param is right 
  // or not to redirect to 404 page component.
  const param = route.paramMap.get['slug'];
  return true;
};


What does this do? I couldn't understand

@user27023959 This is a fairly simple route guard. Check out docs for route guard.

@user27023959 check out docs for route guard. In simple terms it allows you to execute a function that may be let you or not pass to the route. You have to write the logic to determine if your dynamic parameter makes sense in your url.

@MarcGuillem but i have to see status code. for my job

@user27023959 sorry but if you can't provide an example with stackblitz or a proper written full description i can't help you.

If I understand your problem right, I think you can handle the 404 error with a NotFound Component. You must just add a entry in your routes-array to „navigate“ to your customized NotFound Component if the URL input is invalid, like blog/contactasdfasdf or blog/invalid-url or blog/artificial-intelligence, as you mentioned above.
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: ‘contact’, component: ContactComponent },
   { path: ‘blog’, component: BlogComponent },
   { path: ‘blog/:slug’, component: BlogDetailComponent },
   { path: ‘**’, component: NotFoundComponent }
];


With this he still has to find a way to differentiate between valid and invalid slug values in the moment when he want to visit blog/:slug route if not all slug values are allowed. He would still need a route guard or some other mechanism. This will redirect to NotFoundComponent component if no other route is matched or valid.

@MilosStojanovic I already code it like this, but when I write something invalid to the url on the blog detail pages, it still works with a 200 status code.

@user27023959 If you code it like in this answer, you will get 200 status code and you will be redirected to NotFoundComponent. If you want to change status code, you will have to do it manually. What do you want to happen when you enter invalid url?

When I write something random to the url on all pages, it goes to the NotFound component and gives a 404 error. Only when I write something random to the url on the blog detail pages, it goes to the NotFoundComponent but it doesn't give a 404 error. I want to get a 404 on blog:slug pages as well.
@MilosStojanovic

@user27023959 Where do you see that you get 404 result code?

@MilosStojanovic network

@user27023959 Thing is, when I try to recreate your routes example, I never get 404 response. Honestly, I don't see how I would get that response since response is returned from server and on frontend you can only handle response. Can you please recreate that behavior and post image or video of that?
